# How to add dynamic class to gutenberg blocks generated using ACF when adding each time

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add a dynamic class to my ACF generated block when added each time on the page.What i need is to automatically populate the Additional class metafield when a block is added.Is there any way to do this.
[I need to fill this field automatically in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p4my.png)